# Look at this "double" list - is it correct?

Tags: lists

"the article demonstrated that managers often utilize insight, vision, and intuition, rather than statistics, factual details, and reports."

I used this sentence. I wanted to know if this kind of "double" list is acceptable in English writing. It seems pretty legitimate, but I wanted to try and find the official answer.

Comment: This looks good to me. I don't know what counts for you as an "official answer!

Answer (score 1):

Some consider the three-part list to be the second-most powerful tool in English. Using two like that increases the impact of both.

The comma in *intuition, rather* is not necessary and here, it spoils the flow.

As TonyK says, that hyphen has no place. The first of a pair of hyphens opens an aside, which needs to be closed with the second, as for instance: *the article demonstrated that managers - among others - often utilize insight, vision, and intuition rather than statistics, factual details, and reports*

Comment: As a side note, It would be an em dash, not a hyphen.

Comment: Thanks AlannaRose and while you can find very detailed expositions on the different uses of hyphens, en- and em-dashes in places like http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/091502enem.htm those are not fast rules and they have no place in grammar; only in typography and even there, rather archaically.

Grammatically it might just be possible to distinguish hyphens from all dashes too soon, you're into pin dancing.

Answer (score -2):

I shall use a hyphen to make the sentence look better.
**"the article demonstrated that managers often utilize insight, vision, and intuition- rather than statistics, factual details, and reports."**

Comment: No, that is not a correct use of the hyphen in educated English.